# Looking to sort the column where cell renders select with ANTD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, final-form

I am using the antd table to render the data and render `select` as cell data like the one below in the image, but having problems with sorting the same column based on the selected option name. The dataIndex is Id, and I am using that dataIndex to render the select option inside the cell.

Below is the code, and this is the  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5wjT.png) where I am rendering the cell.

```
export const compareStrings = (a, b) =>
     a?.toString()?.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'accent' 
    });
    const BTable = ({ tableId }) => {
          const COLUMNS = [
          {
            title: 'Utility Type',
            dataIndex: 'utilityTypeId',
            sorter: (a, b) => {
               const aname = a.utilityTypeId.props.options.find(
               (sm) => sm.utilityTypeId === a.utilityTypeId.props.name
               )?.name;
               const bname = b.utilityTypeId.props.options.find(
               (sm) => sm.utilityTypeId === a.utilityTypeId.props.name
               )?.name;
               return compareStrings(aname, bname);
            }
          },
          {
            title: 'Enduse Type',
            dataIndex: 'enduseTypeId'
          }];
          
          return (
            <FieldArray name={tableId}>
              {({ fields }) => {
                const data = fields.map((name, index) => {
                  return {
                    rowKey: index,
                    enduseTypeId: (
                      <Field
                        name={`${name}.enduseTypeId`}
                        component={AntdSelectIdAdapter}
                        options={enduseTypesData?.enduseTypes}
                        render={(o) => o.name}
                      />
                    ),
                    utilityTypeId: (
                      <Field
                        name={`${name}.utilityTypeId`}
                        component={AntdSelectIdAdapter}
                        options={utilityTypesData?.utilityTypes}
                        render={(o) => o.name}
                      />
                    ),
                  };
                });
                return (
                  <Table
                    dataSource={data}
                    columns={COLUMNS}         
                    rowKey="rowKey"                      
                  />
                );
              }}
            </FieldArray>
          );
        };
```

Could anyone please tell me how to sort the column having a drop-down based on the selected value in select? Also, please let me know if you need more information.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Update: I have tried the approach of how to sort, but it does not work